# Classifying 10 top features using SVM

Tags: r, classification, data-visualization, svm

I'm new in R. I have a problem with classification using SVM. In my train_data, I have 82 samples and 25770 features while in my test_data I have 36 samples and 25770 features. The last column is the class-label. I would like to classify my samples into "normal/control/0" and "diabetes/1" using 10 top features/genes that I gained from Feature Selection. From feature selection, I have this:
[image: See image : 10 Top Features from Feature Selection]

And this is my code for classification:

```
training_dataset<-data.frame(train_data[,top.features$FeatureID],y=train_data[,ncol(train_data)])
training_dataset$y<-factor(training_dataset$y)
test_data$y<-factor(test_data$y)

svm_RBF<-function(class.dataset,c,gamma,test.data){
class.dataset$y=factor(class.dataset$y)
svm.RBF=svm(y~., data=class.dataset,cost=c,gamma=gamma,kernel='radial',types='C-classification')
predict.svm.RBF=predict(svm.RBF,test.data)
confusionMatrix.RBF=confusionMatrix(predict.svm.RBF,test.data$y)
print(confusionMatrix.RBF)
plot.confusionMatrix.RBF<-function(confusionMatrix.RBF){
mytitle<-paste("Accuracy", percent_format()(confusionMatrix.RBF$overall[1]), "dan Balanced Accuracy",
               percent_format()(confusionMatrix.RBF$byClass[8]))
p<-ggplot(data = as.data.frame(confusionMatrix.RBF$table),
          aes(x=Reference,y=Prediction))+
  geom_tile(aes(fill=log(Freq)),colour = "white")+
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high = "steelblue")+
  geom_text(aes(x=Reference, y=Prediction, label=Freq))+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  ggtitle(mytitle)
return(p)
}
print(plot.confusionMatrix.RBF(confusionMatrix.RBF))
print(roc.curve(test.data$y, predict.svm.RBF))
}

training_dataset10<-data.frame(training_dataset[,1:10],y=training_dataset[,ncol(training_dataset)])
svm_RBF_10<-svm_RBF(train_dataset10,32,0.001953125,test_data)
```

Now the problem is, the model that I just made have high accuracy but low in AUC. My questions are :

1. Is this the correct way to do classification using 10 top features?
2. Is this the correct way to plot my classifier?
3. Do you have a better suggestion to increase my AUC? The data already balanced.

I already did generalization error and parameter tuning so those are the best parameter that I get.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, why are you only using one classifier?  See this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/451831/32398) on data mining theorems and problems with using one classifier.  You should be using linear regression first, possibly followed by logistic regression, Naive Bayes, k-nearest neighbor, linear discriminant analysis, etc.  You should also be considering use of an ensemble of classifiers based on majority committee voting.

You should also consider cross-validation.

Take a look at the different ROC-AUC curves from different classifiers [here](https://www.nxglogic.com/outputexplorer.html)