Which classic ML algorithms can be written as neural networks?
Many classic machine learning algorithms can be reframed as simple neural networks.
For instance:

Linear regression can be thought of as a neural network with one linear layer with $p$ inputs and $1$ output using MSE as the loss function.
Logistic regression can be thought of as a neural network with one linear layer with $p$ inputs, $1$ outputs, a sigmoid activation function, and using binary cross-entropy as the loss function.
Multinomial logistic regression is the same as above, but with $p$ inputs, $c$ outputs, softmax activation and categorical cross-entropy.

What other classic algorithms can be rephrased in this way?  For example, can we write quadratic discriminant analysis in this form?  This is a particularly interesting example for me because QDA models the full joint distribution, rather than just the conditional distributions as in the above examples.
Here, by Neural Network, I mean a function of the form
$f_\theta : \mathbb{R}^{p_0} \stackrel{L_0}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_1} \stackrel{\sigma_1}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_1} \stackrel{L_1}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_2} \stackrel{\sigma_2}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_k} \dots \stackrel{L_k}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_{k+1}} \stackrel{\sigma_{k+1}}{\to} \mathbb{R}^{p_{k+1}}$
where the $L_i$ are linear, and the $\sigma_i$ are non-linear functions which are applied coordinate-wise.
This is paired with a loss function $\ell(\theta)$ which we want to minimize.

Closely related https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362425/what-is-an-artificial-neural-network

I think you need to clarify what, exactly, you mean by a neural network. The classic interpretation is to have each neuron after the input layer be a linear combination and then an activation function of the previous layer, so a generalized linear model. If you relax that to allow each such neuron to be an arbitrary function, say QDA, of the previous layer, then everything is a neural network.

@Dave I added the definition of neural network I would like to work with for the purposes of this question.
